# How to create PushRow function with generic parameter type

Tags: swift, generics, eureka-forms

Im having different functions for creating PushRow with different types.
it includes both string type and custom defined types also. How to merge these functions to a single one which accept generic parameter for creating PushRow

```
fileprivate func createPushRow1() {     
    form +++ Section(label)
        <<< PushRow<String>(String(typeId)) {
        $0.title = label.lowercased()
        $0.selectorTitle = "Pick " + label.lowercased()
        $0.options = optionList
        }.onChange({ [unowned self] row in
           row.value = row.value
        })
}

fileprivate func createPushRow2() {
     self.form +++ Section(label)
          <<< PushRow<Priority>(String(typeId)) {
          $0.title = label.lowercased()
          $0.selectorTitle = "Pick " + label.lowercased()
          $0.options = priorityList
          $0.displayValueFor = {
              guard let priority = $0 else { return nil }
              return priority.name
          }
          $0.onChange({ [] row in
              row.value = row.value
          })
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PushRow` options require conformance to `Equatable`. So assuming your `Priority` class conforms to `Equatable`, you can use the follow function which takes a generic equatable type as a parameter to create a `PushRow`.

```
func createPushRow<T: Equatable>(type: T.Type, options: [T]) {

    self.form +++ Section(label)

        <<< PushRow<T>(String(typeId)) {

            $0.title = label.lowercased()
            $0.selectorTitle = "Pick " + label.lowercased()
            $0.options = options
        }
}
```

You can simply use the function like this.

```
self.createPushRow(type: String.self, options: ["option A", "option B"])
```

However, you need to be careful on your PushRow tag `String(typeId)` though, Eureka does not accept rows with the same tag, so you will probably want to pass unique row tag as another parameter in the generic function.

**Updated**

You can simply conform your `Priority` struct to both `Equatable` and `CustomStringConvertible`.

```
struct Priority: Equatable, CustomStringConvertible {

    let id: Int
    let name: String

    var description: String {
        return self.name
    }

    static func == (lhs: Priority, rhs: Priority) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  How i can add diplayValueFor in different conditions?

Comment: That will be slightly complicated as not all classes conforming to `Equatable` has the parameter `name`. However, if your Priority class is a `NSObject`, then it will be easy. Maybe you can share your `Priority` class codes.

Comment: can we supply it during function call or after creating that row(by fetching onPresent event of row) ?

Comment: maybe you can add in a new parameter `Dictionary<T, String>`, where T is the selected `Equatable` and `String` is the value to display.

Comment: sorry i didn't get that answer, What is mean about NSObject?. can you elaborate as your answer?.

Comment: check the updated answer, maybe you can show the codes of your `Priority` class.

Comment: `struct Priority: Equatable {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
    }`

This is my priority class. What are the changes to be done in class and createPushRow() method ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, check out the updated part of the answer.